Error when running apt install: "dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure)"
I'm encountering an error when trying to install packages using apt install. The command always returns the following error. Can someone help me resolve this issue?
trongnp@TRONGNP:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.99.9.12).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up unattended-upgrades (2.3ubuntu0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please do not use comments.
